# Selecting from a subquery into a column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

So say I've got a table called `orders` with a column `zip_code` and a table called `provinces`. `provinces` has the fields `name`, `starting_zip` and `ending_zip` (to indicate that all zip codes between starting and ending zip pertain to this province).

I need to select thousands of orders and include the name of the province they are to ship to. I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT orders.*, p.name
FROM orders, (SELECT name FROM provinces 
    WHERE order.zip_code >= provinces.starting_zip 
    AND order.zip_code <= provinces.ending_zip LIMIT 1) p
WHERE...
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT orders.*, p.name
FROM orders
JOIN (SELECT name FROM provinces 
    WHERE order.zip_code >= provinces.starting_zip 
    AND order.zip_code <= provinces.ending_zip LIMIT 1) p
WHERE...
```

Also:

```
SELECT orders.*, (SELECT name FROM provinces 
    WHERE order.zip_code >= provinces.starting_zip 
    AND order.zip_code <= provinces.ending_zip LIMIT 1) as name
FROM orders
WHERE...
```

No matter what I do though, I get an error like:

```
"Unknown column 'order.zip_code' in 'where clause'
```

It makes sense that the subselect wouldn't have the scope to access info from the main select, but any idea how I could get this to work?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: thanks, @renis. just a typo in my question but my problem actually was a different typo in my real query.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry. I'll provide MCVEs in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
SELECT orders.*, 
(
    SELECT name 
    FROM provinces 
    WHERE orders.zip_code >= provinces.starting_zip 
    AND orders.zip_code <= provinces.ending_zip 
    LIMIT 1
) as name
FROM orders
WHERE...
```

I do not really see why this should be in the `FROM` statement. You are anyway selecting just the name column

**Update**

Did you see that I changed the tables name in the subquery? The `FROM` statement looks like this:

```
FROM orders
```

But the `WHERE` clause look like this:

```
WHERE order.zip_code >= provinces.starting_zip 
AND order.zip_code <= provinces.ending_zip
```

I have changed it in the query to this:

```
WHERE orders.zip_code >= provinces.starting_zip 
AND orders.zip_code <= provinces.ending_zip
```

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that I tried that as well... same problem as the others

Comment: @Chris : Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. That was actually just a typo in my question, but I figured it out (was due to a different typo in my actual code, heh). I like your answer tho so I'll accept it